# How to @Autowired a test controller invoked by WebTestClient in @WebFluxTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a Controller just for tests with dummy apis

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
  @Autowired
  private org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer tracer;

  @GetMapping("/trace")
  public Mono<String> traceTest() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here's my test

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = TestController.class)
public MyTest {
  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webClient;

  @Test
  public void testTrace() {
    webClient.get().uri("/trace")...
  }
}
```

When I try to run this, my Tracer is not Autowired.

Of course, if I change my test to a @SpringBootTest, it all works

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public MyTest {
  ...
}
```

But I'd like to avoid autowiring my entire spring application. How can I get TestController to be auto-configured?

Answer (score 1):

The `@WebFluxTest` annotation populates a Spring TestContext with only a subset of the relevant beans:

> @WebFluxTest auto-configures the Spring WebFlux infrastructure and
> limits scanned beans to @Controller, @ControllerAdvice,
> @JsonComponent, Converter, GenericConverter, WebFilter, and
> WebFluxConfigurer. Regular @Component and @ConfigurationProperties
> beans are not scanned when the @WebFluxTest annotation is used.
> @EnableConfigurationProperties can be used to include
> @ConfigurationProperties beans. from [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-webflux-tests)

Your `Tracer` won't be part of this TestContext out-of-the-box.

For your `@WebFluxTest` you can provide a mocked version of this bean with `@MockBean`:

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = TestController.class)
public MyTest {
  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webClient;

  @MockBean
  private Tracer tracer;

  @Test
  public void testTrace() {
    webClient.get().uri("/trace")...
  }
}
```

... and if you want to test the full integration I would rather use `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: I think using @MockBean is an acceptable way of doing it, but is there no way to configure just that one Autowired bean?